# react-native: flexbox alignment

Tags: react-native, flexbox, expo

I have a relatively simple layout and i can't figure out why the green call button won't align against the right hand side of the container. (the right border of the green button should align with the right edge of the blue pencil icon).
Have I configured my flexboxes incorrectly?

[image: screenshot]

Here's the code

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
        <Text h3 style={{ flex: 1 }}>{contact.name}</Text>
        <Icon
                style={{ flex: 0 }}
                name="edit"
                onPress={this.handleEditContact}
                color="royalblue"
                size={20}
                underlayColor="whitesmoke"
                />

    </View>
    <View style={[styles.rowContainer, {marginTop: 10}]}>
        <PhoneText  style={{ flex:1 }}
                    phone={contact.phone} />
        <Button buttonStyle={{ flex: 0 }}
                title="Call"
                iconRight
                icon={{name:'phone'}}
                backgroundColor='mediumseagreen'
                borderRadius={5}
                underlayColor='whitesmoke'/>

    </View>
    <Text>Notes:</Text>
    <Text style={{ flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>{contact.notes}</Text>
</View>
```

Here are the style definitions:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex: 1,
        margin: 10,
        padding: 10,
        borderWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
        borderRadius: 5,
        borderColor: 'gainsboro',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
    },
    rowContainer:{
        flex: 0,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
});
```

Comment: I've tested with correct result. have you checked is there any additional margin between phone image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @TimH I looked at the source to discover that the prop I want is 
containerViewStyle, and not buttonStyle. duhh... right?

```
<Button containerViewStyle={{ marginRight: 0 }} .... />
```

Answer (score 1):

This margin is caused by the Button Component of react-native-elements. If you take a look into the source, you will find a styleObject with a container specified.

```
container: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    marginLeft: 15,
    marginRight: 15,
},
```

Just remove the marginRight property and you'll get your wished alignment. This would be a quick & dirty solution. Probably you should create your own fork of the Button component. I hope i could help you.

Comment: thanks. this led me down the right path. the correct way to do this is to pass marginRight: 0 on the containerViewStyle prop.